# kswap0 take all CPU during ping command

Tags: linux, cpu, ping, swap

I observing a strange behaviour on my embedded device (with YOCTO). I ping a server via WiFi and after several hours (around 100h), the kswap0 take all CPU so to block the board.
Now, some questions :

1. is not clear how a simple ping can generate this
2. how can skip this ? What's happen if I set to 0 vm.swappiness=0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Is ping printing output on a GUI terminal emulator with unlimited scrollback history, using up all your RAM?  Or to a file in tmpfs?  Don't do that.  Do you have swap space, or compressed swap to RAM?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I'm using a GUI with unlimited scroll and a check with swapon -s command on device show the swap area  (total, free and used) equal to 0.    
I must deduce that there is no swap area on the device

Comment: Ok, then approaching an out-of-memory condition probably results in thrashing zswap (compressing and decompressing pages to other RAM), assuming your system has zswap enabled.  It doesn't use a backing device so won't appear in `swapon -s` output.  Check `dmesg` for a message like `zswap: loaded using pool lz4/z3fold`.  Eventually it will have to invoke the OOM killer which kills some process, probably the process doing unlimited-scrollback in the GUI on your yocto system.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, none messages like zswap are present in dmes, in '/sys/kernel/debug' there is not 'zswap' file and 'cat/proc/swaps' output is empty.

Comment: Ok, then IDK what `kswap0` would be doing.